# Python count the number of occurrences and also the elements with maximum occurences separately after splitting the string in list from dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with the values as list of strings as follows:

```
dict_1 = { 
    0: ['john 1', 'jacob 2', 'john 3', 'john 4', 'jacob 7', 'astor 6', 'michael 8', 'michael 9'],
    1: ['jacob 11', 'jacob 13', 'astor 15', 'astor 17', 'michael 20'] 
}
```

I need to count the number of times a name has occurred in the lists of a particular key in the dictionary. Also I need to output the elements with max count separately. So the output I need is like this:

```
Key 0
john 3
jacob 2
astor 1
michael 2
Max element count: 
john 3

Key 1
jacob 2
astor 2
michael 1
Max element count: 
jacob 2
astor 2
```

How can I do this in the fastest way possible in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pattern is fixed and you opt for speed, I'd make a list instead of dict with keys `0, 1, ..`, use generator expression for `collections.Counter` 
and also subtract the name as `entry[:entry.index(" ")]`:

```
import operator as op
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

dict_1 = {0: ['john 1', 'jacob 2', 'john 3', 'john 4', 'jacob 7', 'astor 6', 'michael 8', 'michael 9'], 1: ['jacob 11', 'jacob 13', 'astor 15', 'astor 17', 'michael 20']}

all_scores = [Counter(entry[:entry.index(" ")] for entry in list_).most_common() for list_ in dict_1.values()]
# [[('john', 3), ('jacob', 2), ('michael', 2), ('astor', 1)], [('jacob', 2), ('astor', 2), ('michael', 1)]]

max_scores = [list(next(groupby(scores, key=op.itemgetter(1)))[1]) for scores in all_scores]
# [[('john', 3)], [('jacob', 2), ('astor', 2)]]

# Report them
for key, (scores, maximums) in enumerate(zip(all_scores, max_scores)):
    print(f"Key {key}")
    for name, score in scores:
        print(name, score)
    print("Max element count:")
    for name, max_score in maximums:
        print(name, max_score)
    print()
```

For getting the maximums, we use one `next` on `groupby`. Since the counts are already coming as sorted from `Counter`, we shouldn't be traversing all the scores; `groupby` is a good and fast suit for this problem which groups according to the second elements i.e. numbers (hence the `op.itemgetter(1)`). Then we cast to list and our desired pairs are in the second element (first element contains the respective numbers).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from @Ajax1234, you asked how to get the max element counts, which you can do something like this (after his answer provides the `vals`):

```
max_per_key = {}
for key, val in vals.items():
    # This gets a list with 1 entry containing the most common element, the [0] pulls the tuple out of the list and the [1] gets the count out of the tuple
    max_count = val.most_common(1)[0][1]
    max_list = [(k, v) for k, v in val.items() if v == max_count]
    max_per_key[key] = max_list
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `re.sub` with `collections.Counter`:

```
import re, collections as col
dict_1 = {0: ['john 1', 'jacob 2', 'john 3', 'john 4', 'jacob 7', 'astor 6', 'michael 8', 'michael 9'], 1: ['jacob 11', 'jacob 13', 'astor 15', 'astor 17', 'michael 20']}
vals = {a:col.Counter([re.sub('\s\d+$', '', k) for k in b]) for a, b in dict_1.items()}
```

The result is a dictionary storing the key along with a `collections.Counter` object storing the number of name occurrences:

```
{0: Counter({'john': 3, 'jacob': 2, 'michael': 2, 'astor': 1}), 1: Counter({'jacob': 2, 'astor': 2, 'michael': 1})}
```

To get the desired printout:

```
for a, b in vals.items():
   print(f'Key {a}')
   print('\n'.join(f'{j} {k}' for j, k in b.items()))
   print()
```

Output:

```
Key 0
john 3
jacob 2
astor 1
michael 2

Key 1
jacob 2
astor 2
michael 1
```

Comment: Ok. What should I do if I need only the max counter from the counter object?

Comment: @Lax_Sam, use `col.Counter(...).most_common(1)`

Comment: Why not split and take the first element, instead of `re.sub`? If the pattern is fixed, it should be faster (though not as readable perhaps)

Comment: @MustafaAydın Yes pattern is fixed.

Comment: @MustafaAydın If I use `most_common` it will output only the first max element. How can I output all the elements which have the same max count?

Comment: @MustafaAydin I have edited the question. Please check it.

Comment: @Lax_Sam, see my answer.